# Using a background image in UV editor? To trace tattoos with paint mode

Tags: uv, image

I have a 3D model which has it's own textures and UV. And I want to draw some tattoos on these textures.

But I want to display an reference image, on top in the UV editor (in paint mode). And then I want to trace the reference image, and I want the paint to go on the original texture.

Is this possible? Thank You.

Comment: have you tried applying your tattoo to the brush as a texture and setting the Brush Mapping to Stencil? i think this is what you're looking for :]

Comment: @Zac Thank you for this suggestion. For now this seems to be the best solution I have, I have to use this.

However, I am still looking for a way or solution to bring up my tattoo as a transparent overlay int he UV Editor, so that I can go into paint mode there and re-trace the tattoo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Skip the UV/Image editor if you want to, and then you have some possibilities that might help you.

Turn on the Images as Planes addon that is bundled with Blender,import your tattoo reference image using shift-a 'add images as planes', and set the image shader to shadeless in the import dialogue before import. Tab to Texture Paint mode, and then in the Slots tab add a new image with 0 transparencey (click the color tab and then slide the alpha slider to 0). This is now on top of your original image of the tattoo, similar to GIMP or Krita. Use the paint tools to trace your reference until you are satisfied with it, and then you can go to the UV/Image Editor and choose the new 0 alpha image - there, save it to the directory of your choice, like desktop for instance. Make sure to choose RGBA so that you still can use the alpha later.

Now you can load this image as a stencil brush as described, and either paint in the UV/Image Editor or in the 3D view on the model with the original textures.

Comment: Thanks, really! This makes sense :) I haven't tried it, but my logic already tells me this will work!

Comment: It should work well, as this is a normal thing for me to do myself as a way to create brushes or to create high res drawings from low res photos - because the new slots can have higher resolution than the imported image :D

Answer (score 0):

**All steps will be done in UV Image Editor (Paint Mode).**

1. Create **New Texture Mask**, name it as you want.
2. Choose **Mask Mapping > Stencil**.
3. Go to **Properties Panel > Texture**.
4. Select **Brush Mask - *"Your texture name"***.
5. Load your tattoo image.

   *If you have it white on black color you can skip those steps.*
6. Under **Image Sampling Tab** select **Calculate**.
7. Under **Colors Tab** check **Ramp** and switch color handles and adjust if needed.
8. Go back to **UV Image Editor** and trace your mask.

> Note: Manipulating Stencil in Mask mode is a bit different.
>
> - <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>RightClick</kbd> - Move
> - <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>RightClick</kbd> - Scale
> - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>RightClick</kbd> - Rotate

[image: Steps]