# How to add these stripes to my fender?

Tags: uv

I'm working on renders for a corvette I modeled via a course from cgmasters. On one of the front fenders, I want to add Grand Sport stripes like shown here:

[image]

The car paint is blue, and I want to do white stripes. My rough guess is that I would create the stripes as an image, then UV unwrap the fender and apply the image to the wrap. I feel like I may be missing something though. Any help is appreciated.

Note: I tried this method of adding a texture as a decal and shrinkwrapping it. But because this is something that needs to stop precisely in some places, I cannot get it to work.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QGxMY2lMoLw

Comment: just unwrap, add a transparent image texture, and paint the stripes in texture paint mode. then yo can add fine details to the texture in gimp, or in photoshop.
There is also the simplest way - make stripes in geometry (knife tool (K)), and just assign another material (white) to those faces.

Comment: Check my answer here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/84236/using-a-background-image-in-uv-editor-to-trace-tattoos-with-paint-mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said you can simply unwrap:

- Create your stripes with a transparent background and save it as PNG.
- Make an unwrap of the part of the mesh that will display the stripes and give this UVmap the name you want.
- Duplicate your basic car material and assign this copy to this part of the mesh.
- In this material, mix your basic node(s) with the one(s) you specifically want to give to the stripes.
- Add an *Image Texture* node, load the PNG, and use the *Alpha* output as the factor of a *Mix Shader*.
- In the *Image Texture* node, use *Clip* instead of *Repeat* so that the stripes won't repeat.
- Plug an *Input* > *UV Map* node in the *Vector* of the *Image Texture* node and load the UVmap you've created in this *UV Map* node.
- Now adjust the UV in the *UV/Image Editor* until the stripes is correctly displayed.

[image]

Comment: After following these steps, what I am seeing is a white color all over the fender. In the UV I don't see the image (I didn't specifically add it there as well - but you didn't say to do so - I tried anyway and it didn't change anything.) I did assign the new material to the vertices. Here are my settings:

Can't get the markdown for an image to work, but here's a link to my settings. 

https://www.dropbox.com/s/5al2nb07oh9r8kj/settings.png?dl=0

Comment: perhaps share your file, and please pack the image you've used before saving